# Regular expression for path validation?

Tags: regex

I have a path and need to write a regular expression to filter the path with Common-io library.

The path should not contain:

- `req/com/res`,
- `res/com/req`,
- `req/al/res`,
- `res/al/req`,
- `_svn`

and path should end with `.xml`.

```
 FileUtils.listFiles(aFile, new RegexFileFilter("^(.*?)"), TrueFileFilter.INSTANCE)
```

If I do it like this, this returns all the xmls.

I don't have any idea about regex; could someone please give an idea how to do this?

Comment: What about `^(?!.*(?:req\/(?:com|al)\/re[sq]|_svn)).*\.xml$`?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon.  (a) You should learn the basics of regexes. (b) You should identify the host language you're using and use that in the tags. (c) You should show what you've tried.  Your regex allows anything through; it doesn't check for `xml` or any of your verboten strings.  We'll help people making an honest attempt at solving their problem; we're considerably more reluctant to help those who don't.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Sure I will follow the instruction. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: @stribizhev still I can see the files with "_svn".

Comment: Note that your specification is not clear about whether `/usr/autres/al/requiem/fascinating.xml` should be allowed through.  It contains `res/al/req`, but only as parts of bigger words within the path. What about `/usr/centres/al/request.xml`?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler it should allow if path like /res/al/req/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regex:

```
^(?i)(?!.*(?:re[qs]/(?:com|al)/re[sq]|_svn)).*\\.xml$
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/aL5aM3/2)

The `(?i)` pattern makes it case-insensitive. Remove if you want to make the search case-sensitive. The `(?!.*(?:re[qs]/(?:com|al)/re[sq]|_svn))` pattern makes sure we do not allow any of the forbidden strings inside the path.

If you want to only account for the whole words, add `\b`:

```
^(?i)(?!.*\\b(?:re[qs]/(?:com|al)/re[sq]|_svn)\\b).*\\.xml$
```

See [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/aL5aM3/3)

Note in Java-style regex we do not need to escape `/` and we have to double-escape special characters.